# Get back to last github commit

Tags: git, github

I would like to get back to my last github commit but I dont know how to proceed. 
Here is my git log were the first one is my last one

```
commit 0d74db9ccbdec3ffc42c42216d1352e9bee51b62 (HEAD -> master, 
origin/master)
Author: filipmyllari <fm222hp@student.lnu.se>
Date:   Tue May 29 14:26:15 2018 +0200

Recontructing navigation

commit e5e7f7002f76f47e394c097f770e325c7058002d
Author: filipmyllari <fm222hp@student.lnu.se>
Date:   Wed May 23 14:29:44 2018 +0200

Small design tweaks and bug fixes

commit af133f818667edb12a880accd0be75f845da6a1c
:
```

Comment: What do you mean with get back .... you already are ... or do you mean to undo it?

Comment: You mean make a reverse? Check for how to make a reverse

Comment: means do you want to remove all the changes made after that commit. ?

Answer (score 0):

git checkout commitid

in your case

git checkout e5e7f7

Comment: This will move him to a detached HEAD ... unless he uses the `-b` option.

Answer (score 0):

To get back last git commit run simply

```
git checkout last_commit_id
```

Answer (score 0):

for removing last changes done after a particular Commit try
`git reset --hard`. By using this command the head will move to that last commit.